# Recursive search on multiple properties

Tags: javascript, recursion

Here is some JSON data I have :

```
[
    {
        "name" : "X",
        "children" : [
            {
                "name" : "Y"
            },
            {
                "name" : "Z"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name" : "A",
        "options" : [
            {
                "children" : [
                    {
                        "name" : "B"
                    },
                    {
                        "name" : "C"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "children" : [
                    {
                        "name" : "D"
                    },
                    {
                        "name" : "E"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "children" : [
            {
                "name" : "F"
            },
            {
                "name" : "G"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I want to retrieve the object that matches the name I'm looking for.
My problem is, since there are arrays of data,

- if use a return on the recusive call and dive into the 1st array, it will stop searching after the last item of this array.
- if I don't put the return on the recursive call, I can't get the returned value.

What would be the best algo to get the matching object such as :

```
{
    "name" : F
}
```

For example, if I'm looking for **F**

Comment: do you have a valid object?

Comment: edited. The real one contains company information, I wanted to make one smaller and more clear.. Now it's valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so according to the posts I'm not able to avoid storing the return value and check if it's null or not. I tought about doing that but I find this dirty and not optimized.

```
function findField(fieldName, scope = fields){
    let i;
    let result;
    for(i=0; i < scope.length; i++){
        if(scope[i].name === fieldName){
            return scope[i];
        }
        else if ("options" in scope[i]){
            let j;
            for(j=0; j < scope[i].options.length; j++){
                result = findField(fieldName, scope[i].options[j].children)
                if(result) return result
            }
        }
        else {
            result = findField(fieldName, scope[i].children)
            if(result) return result
        }
    }
    return null
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

Below is a recursive code should test the incoming parameter whether it is an array (and check each element) or it is an object and checks "name" property and if it is not what we are looking for, runs the same recursive method for each property. Here is the code:

```
retrieveObjectWithName(obj, name)
{
    // if incoming object has property name and it matches our search name
    if (obj.name === name) {
        return obj;
    }

    // if incoming object is an array then we iterate through it and test each element
    if (Array.isArray(obj)){
        for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
            var result = retrieveObjectWithName(obj[i], name);
            if (result) {
                return result;
            }
        }
    }

    // if the incoming object is an object then we iterate through each property and test each property
    for (var property in obj) {
        if (object.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
            var result = retrieveObjectWithName(obj[property], name);
            if (result) {
                return result;
            }
        }
    }

    // nothing was found (at least on this level)
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I don't have a single object, it's an array. That's what is causing trouble here. I also wanted to avoid temp variable to check if it was null or not. I've been convinced since the beginning there is a cleaner option

Comment: I thought children property is the only property which may have an array of objects. I fixed the code to accept either array of objects or any object - it will test anything. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You could check the handed over item if is is not object, then return undefined, if the wanted name is found return this object, otherwise iterate the values form the object and check nested objects.

Methods:

- pattern for checking an object which is not `null`,
- [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) for getting all values of an object,
- [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) which allows a short circuit, if the return value is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) (in this case an object is found),
- a recursive call which returns a value from deep nested calls.

```js
function getObject(object, name) {
    var temp;
    if (!object || typeof object !== 'object') return;
    if (object.name === name) return object;            
    Object.values(object).some(o => temp = getObject(o, name));
    return temp;
}

var data = [{ name: 'X', children: [{ name: 'Y' }, { name: 'Z' }] }, { name: 'A', options: [{ children: [{ name: 'B' }, { name: 'C' }] }, { children: [{ name: 'D' }, { name: 'E' }] }], children: [{ name: 'F' }, { name: 'G' }] }];

console.log(getObject(data, 'F'));
console.log(getObject(data, 'A'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Object.values(object).some(o => temp = getObject(o, name)); Any reference about that ?

Comment: what means reference?

Answer (score 0):

this code can be forever nested.

```
const data = [{
    name: 'jamal 1',
    options: [{
        children: [{
            name: 'jamal 1 1 1',
        }, {
            name: 'jamal 1 1 2',
        }],
    }, {
        children: [{

            name: 'jamal 1 2 1',
        }, {
            name: 'jamal 1 2 2',
        }],
    }],
}, {
    name: 'jamal 2',
    children: [{
        name: 'jamal 2 1',

    }, {
        name: 'jamal 2 2',
    }],
}];

function compare(obj, comp) {
    for (const key in comp) {

        console.log(obj[key], comp[key]);
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            if (obj[key] != comp[key]) {
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

function search(object, query) {
    for (const item of object) {
        if (compare(item, query)) {
            return item;
        } else if (Array.isArray(item.options)) {
            const result = search(item.options, query);
            if (result) return result;
        } else if (Array.isArray(item.children)) {
            const result = search(item.children, query);
            if (result) return result;
        }
    }
    return null;
}


console.log(search(data, {name: 'jamal 1 1 2'})); // result {name: 'jamal 1 1 2'}
```

#### edit

sorry about the name, it's just for testing :)